# VBA to pass a conditional operator as a variable to an if statement

Tags: vba, variables, if-statement, conditional-statements

I would like to perform an if statement where the condition is also a variable. something like:

```
If Var1 Var2 Var3 Then DoStuff
```

where for examle Var1 = 5, Var2 = ">" and Var3 = "2"
How can you make VBA understand this as:

```
If 5 > 2 Then DoStuff
```

Comment: You cannot do that directly with VBA, you'll have to abstract it somehow.  Can you list what all of the possible choices for your condition-variable (`Var2`) should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an indirect way to do it, using `Evaluate`

```
Sub test()
Dim x As String, y As String, z As String
x = "5"
y = ">"
z = "2"

If Application.Evaluate("IF(" & x & y & z & ", true, false)") Then
    MsgBox "yes"
Else
    MsgBox "no"
End If
End Sub
```

edit: I have tested this in Excel VBA. If you are not using Excel VBA, please edit the tags.

Comment: If using VBA in Microsoft Access, `Evaluate()` is not available.  The hopeful-looking function `Eval()` is not the same (but maybe worth trying).